# How can i change the name of a bookmarklet after its added?

Tags: javascript, html, rename, bookmarklet

Is there any way to change the name of a bookmarklet the moment its added to the users bookmarks?

Like for example, lets say i have this link named "bookmarklet", but when you drag it onto your bookmarks, it changes name to something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name on mousedown and dragstart events

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Hi!');" ondragstart="this.innerHTML='bookmarklet'" onmousedown="this.innerHTML='Bookmarks Bar Item'">bookmarklet</a>
```

jsFiddle of this code - https://jsfiddle.net/kupdwj5q/22/

Comment: Ill try it! If it work i wil give you the green thingy